# How can I efficiently restructure my dataset for EDA in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am at the beginning of learning pandas, and have found an excel dataset, exported to csv. It consists of a number of variables for 40 unique departments. Structured like below, but with variables A, B, C, etc reported for 10 years for each department.

| Department | VariableA(2010) | VariableA(2011) | VariableB(2010) | VariableB(2011) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12000 | 13000 | 12500 | 13040 |
| B | 14000 | 15000 | 12070 | 13060 |

I am thinking this will be hard to analyse in pandas, and therefore the dataset will need to be restructured in excel, prior to exporting as csv and then importing into pandas.

I have tried restructuring the dataset as follows, thinking this will allow for easier data analysis in pandas.

| Year | Department | Variable A | Variable B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | A | 12000 | 12500 |
| 2010 | B | 14000 | 12070 |
| 2011 | A | 13000 | 13040 |
| 2011 | B | 15000 | 13060 |

However, this is very tedious to do by hand and prone to error.  I have not found yet a way of manipulating/restructuring the data in pandas as shown in the second table. May I ask then if there is a method I am missing and should investigate please? Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

[`.wide_to_long()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['VariableA', 'VariableB'], suffix=r'[(]\d+[)]', i='Department', j='Year')
```

```
                   VariableA  VariableB
Department Year                        
A          (2010)      12000      12500
B          (2010)      14000      12070
A          (2011)      13000      13040
B          (2011)      15000      13060
```

You can `.reset_index()` and remove the `()` from the resulting `Year` column if required.

Comment: Thank you @jqurious. I tried this method and it worked well too on my dataset. Much appreciated.